# Why Leibniz algebras are called on this way?

Tags: terminology, lie-algebras, nonassociative-algebras

I´m interested to know the reason to call the Leibniz algebras on this way.

I know that previously they were known as $D$-algebras

Why Loday chose this name?

Did Leibniz study something related?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called after Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz for the *derivation rule*, also called [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule). In the Lie case it is just the Jacobi identity, namely that the adjoint operators are derivations of the Lie algebra: 
$$[x,[y,z]]=[[x,y],z]+[y,[x,z]]$$
Loday chose the word **Leibniz algebra** for a nonassociative algebra, where we only have the Jacobi identity but not the skew-symmetry. The dual operad he called **Zinbiel**, which is Leibniz read backwards.

Comment: Note that this is *one lift* of the Jacobi identity, and not the most naive one (it makes sense to consider the class of algebras satisfying Jacobi in its usual form $a(bc)+b(ca)+c(ab)=0$; I guess it's considered less interesting than Leibniz algebras).

Comment: @YCor Yes, such algebras (and special classes of it) are also considered, see our article [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_50_jacobi_jordan.pdf), but Leibniz algebras are probably more interesting ($K$-theory, (co)homology, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Leibniz algebras are defined as vector spaces $L$ endowed with a bilinear application $[,]\colon L\times L\to L$ such that the identity
$$[x,[y,z]]=[[x,y],z]+[y,[x,z]]$$
holds for all $x,y,z\in L$. This can be equivalently rephrased as asking that for all $x$, the morphism
$$\delta_x\colon L\to L\colon y\mapsto [x,y]$$
satisfies the identity
$$\delta_x([y,z])=[\delta_x(y),z]+[y,\delta_x(z)],$$
and this is often called the **Leibniz identity**, hence the name. It means that $\delta_x$ is a derivation of $(L,[,])$, and in fact the identity above also implies that $\delta:L\to Der(L)$ is a morphism of Leibniz algebras.